# Work on Laravel project as a team

Tags: php, laravel, web

My team and I are trying to work on a web development project using Laravel. We want to work on separate files of the same project simultaneously, but since Laravel generates a user specific code for a project we cannot sync our files properly.

Comment: what user specific code?

Comment: Are you using source control? I'm working on a laravel project for a class right now, and we are using Git. You can add files to the .gitignore file and they will be excluded, so everyone can have their own local copies. Some of the files/directories we ignore include database.php, the vendor directory, etc.

Comment: remove "app/storage" folder from your VCS.